# Click on scrollbar effects on datagrid

Tags: wpfdatagrid

[image]

I have 2 datagrid on click i add item in other as in image but when i click on scroll bar Thumb or shaft multi time for scrolling it add item on other datagrid Please help me on this

here is Code

```
                    <DataGrid Name="dgMenu" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Margin="5,0,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeight="25"  AlternatingRowBackground="{StaticResource AlternateRowBackgroundBrush}" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              HeadersVisibility="Column" SelectionUnit="FullRow" ItemsSource="{Binding DgMenuCollection,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding DgSelectedMenu,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" PreviewKeyUp="dgMenu_PreviewKeyUp"
              VerticalGridLinesBrush="{StaticResource GridLineColorBrush}" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{StaticResource GridLineColorBrush}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" MouseDoubleClick="dgMenu_MouseDoubleClick">
                        <DataGrid.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonSelectedBrush}"  />
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#A8E3FC" />
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGrid.Resources>
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding PN_Recipe.RecipeCode}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Recipe Name" Binding="{Binding PN_Recipe.RecipeName}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="RecipeHalf Price" Binding="{Binding HalfMenuCost}" Visibility="Collapsed"  />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="MenuFull Price" Binding="{Binding FullMenuCost}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Without code, how do you want us to guess what you have missed or did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the Problem is because of the `PreviewKeyUp="dgMenu_PreviewKeyUp"` Instead of using PreviewKeyUp, you could you Mouse Double Click event to add the item.

If i am mistaken, my apologies.

Regards